# Highlighting current-cat in the Archive, Feeds page of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, list, archive, categories

I needed a category listing in my posts page and I want the current category to be highlighted. I enabled the 'All' category, so consequently, I want the 'All' also to be highlighted when I'm viewing the posts page. So I used the codex and got the following script running.

My script is:

```
<cat>
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('show_option_all=All&hide_empty=0&title_li=&current_category=All'); ?>
</ul>
</cat>
```

Do I have to run an IF conditional on my archive.php file to get the category ID and highlight it using CSS class 'cat.current-cat'? How do I do it if the category is 'All' since the 'All' doesn't exactly have a category ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The wp_list_categories function by default sets the class "current-cat" to the current category.  You should just have to add some CSS to your page to make the "current-cat" different than the others.

EDIT:

You can try setting current_category to 1 in the arguments passed to the function.

Comment: I added the class. This in the posts page where a list of all my posts would appear. But there's no highlighting for any of the categories :( If it works for one of the categories, would it work for the category 'All'? Because that is just a manipulation of the existing categories and not a separate category per se.

Comment: What do you mean you added the class?  Is it showing in your page?  If it is showing, then the CSS is the issue as that is what changes the way that class would display.

Comment: I had added the formatting for the css class cat.current-cat{}. It doesn't show.

Comment: Can you post a link?  It wouldn't be cat.currentcat, it would be li.current-cat